# Inputstream read on bluetooth socket hangs if not used

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, inputstream

I am developing an Android app that communicates with a Bluetooth device.

The device continuously sends information to the phone, but I chose to only read the data when the user wants to: by pressing a start/stop button. A reading service is started/stopped every time, but the connection stays open.

The connection to the device works well, no matter how many times the start/stop button is pressed, but only as long the user doesn't let the app in a "stop" state more than 5 seconds.

**If the user lets the app in "stop" state more than 5 seconds, the program will get stuck in inputstream.read() the next time "start" is pressed.**

I have checked that the socket is still open. 
I know that read() is a blocking function, but in this case it should not block as the device is continuously sending data.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is it possible that the problem really comes from the fact that the socket is not used during a few seconds?

Here is the bit of code that I use for acquiring the data:

```
public void start() {
        if (isStarted()) {
            return;
        }
        task = taskService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int value;
                channel.reset();
                try {
                    while ((value = in.read()) != -1 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        channel.put((byte) (value & 0xFF));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("STRS", "IO error : " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        });

    }

  public void stop() {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return;
        }
        task.cancel();
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return task != null && !task.isDone();
    }
```

Comment: I guess you stop reading from the stream by interrupting the thread, that can be a problem. Also, how are you keeping track of the state (started/stopped) ?

Comment: This function is in a read service that is created/destroyed everytime the user presses start/stop, thus the thread will be created and destroyed each time. Why would that be a problem? I edited my post to include the isStarted function.

Comment: That can be a problem because the `Thread`'s interrupted flag can be cleared by another thread but from the code that you've posted, that doesn't seem to be the case. A problem that I see is that you're not using any kind of synchronization to set/check the state.

Comment: But why would that make the program get stuck in the read() function?
And only in the case where the program has been inactive for a few seconds?

Comment: Something similar could happen to TCP sockets too, you should close the connection when entering background if you are not going to use it.

Comment: But what exactly is happening? The socket, even  if my app isn't using it during the "stopped state", is still open and used by the bluetooth device to send information.  Does it become unresponsive for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with blocking read() from a Bluetooth socket and fixed the issue by spawning a new thread and calling read() in a tight loop, reading the data into a circular buffer. The thread you're currently calling read() on now reads data from the circular buffer so is non blocking e.g.

```
private class ReceiveThread extends Thread {

    private boolean running = true;

    public void stopThread() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; 

        while (running) {
            try {
                // write bytes directly into a circular buffer
                int numBytes = socket.read(readBuffer);

                if (numBytes > 0) {
                    circularBuffer.put(readBuffer, 0, numBytes);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
                running = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // swallow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then read directly from the circular buffer

```
circularBuffer.get(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
```

Google for circular buffer implementations in Java, there are many. Just make sure it's thread safe.